# Как отследить направление скролла на станице? JS

Tags: javascript, прокрутка

Допустим, нужно что бы при скролле вниз в консоль выводился 0, а при скролле вверх 1

Comment: `console.log( (prev.y - curr.y) > 0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var scroll = 0;
window.onscroll = onScroll;
function onScroll() {
  var top = window.pageYOffset;
  if (scroll > top) {
    console.log('1');
  } else if (scroll < top) {
    console.log('0');
  }
  scroll = top;
}
```

```css
body {height: 5000px}
```

Answer (score 4):

### Решение с помощью `scrollTop`

```js
let oldScrollTopPosition = 0;

window.onscroll = () => {
 const scrollTopPosition = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
 console.log(oldScrollTopPosition > scrollTopPosition);
 oldScrollTopPosition = scrollTopPosition;
}
```

```css
body {
 min-height: 200vh;
}
```

---

### Решение с помощью `Wheel`

```js
window.onwheel = (e) => console.log(e.deltaY < 0);
```

Comment: deltaY <0 или deltaY >0  так наверно ...мм ?

Comment: @MaximLensky не знаю, у меня и так работает как нужно

Comment: я не  спорю ...плюс поставил

Comment: @MaximLensky , а, вы про wheel написали, сейчас дополню, сначала не понял про что именно вы, спасибо!

Comment: да. wheel кроссбраузерный

Answer (score 0):

```js
let was = 0;

const scrollGoing=(tf)=>{
    if(was !== tf){
        console.log('scroll', tf ? 'down' : 'up', tf);
    }
    was = tf;
};

window.onwheel=({deltaY})=>scrollGoing(deltaY > 0);
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin спасибо пожалуйста здесь нечего дополнять\комментить